# UITableView navigation in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm using mono develop 3.1.1 to build an IOS application. I'm receiving an object reference error (see >>>) from my reference to the navigation controller that I've not declared properly.

My question is what's the best way to declare and instantiate the controller so I'm able to show another view from the point the table cell is selected.

Can someone help me with the correct syntax please?

```
public class TableHelper : UITableViewSource {
    protected string[] tableItems;
    protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";


    public TableHelper (string[] items)
    {
        tableItems = items;
    }




    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return tableItems.Length;
    }


    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        switch (tableItems[indexPath.Row])
        {
        case "one": 
            var DetailViewController = new SupportContactsDetailsScreen ();
            UINavigationController controller = new UINavigationController();
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
            >>>controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(DetailViewController, true);
            break;
        default:
            //Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;
        }
    }


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);

        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

        cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I usually go about doing this is to keep a reference to the main UIViewController (the view controller that holds the UITableView) for that particular set of views and access that Navigation Controller through the NavigationController property. (Another technique taken by Xamarin in the code sample linked below is to pass the UINavigationController in directly.)

So I would alter your class by adding:

```
UIViewController parentViewController;
public TableHelper(string[] items, UIViewController vc)
{
    tableItems = items;
    parentViewController vc;
}

public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    switch (tableItems[indexPath.Row])
    {
    case "one": 
        var DetailViewController = new SupportContactsDetailsScreen ();
        UINavigationController controller = new UINavigationController();
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        parentViewController.NavigationController.PushViewController(DetailViewController, true);
        break;
    default:
        //Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        break;
    }
}
```

Xamarin has a [document](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/User_Interface/Tables) on their docs site as well as [some code](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/TableAndCellStyles/TableAndCellStyles/Code/NavigationTable/NavItemTableSource.cs) on their [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples) that talks about this further. Another important note is what the type of view controller is (regular UIViewController, UITableViewController, etc.).

Comment: Hi Pierce, thanks for the info. I did get the example above from the xamarin docs site. The part I'm struggling with is when I make the call to initialise the class how to I pass the controller in? like table.Source = new TableHelper(tableItems,< reference to controller here >); Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: table.Source = new TableHelper(tableItems, this.NavigationController); Note that one way to do this is to create the master UIViewController class with something like this in your AppDelegate (or wherever you are creating this class): var TableViewController = new UINavigationController(new NameOfMasterViewController()); This will ensure that the calling class has a UINavigationController.

Comment: Hi Pierce, sorry for the late reply. I managed to sort this out. I did what you suggested and created a master or rootview controller. I added a seperate datasource & delegate as well. I'm now able to pass my navigation controller anywhere and invoke new views. thanks for your help.